# C++ how to initialize?

Tags: c++

**add:** I tried on the `fun` below anyone know what is the error?

```
struct node {

  string info;
  node *link;
  node() {
    info = "string";
    link = NULL;

  }

};

void fun( node &node) {

     if (node.link !=NULL) {  
      fun (node.link);
    }

}
```

I get an error message when I use it inside of my functions:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type ‘node&’ from expression of type ‘node*’
```

What is the proper way to initialize it?

Comment: The error is clearly referring to code you have not (accurately) shown us.

Comment: Shall we guess how does your function looks like?

Comment: +1 to give asker a chance to complete the question. The problem seems to not lie int the shown part. Are you sure the error message refers to this part of your code you've shown us?

Comment: @vsz: That is not what upvotes are for.

Comment: @vsz The score of the question has nothing to do with its potential closure. There is a separate "vote to close" system for that.

Comment: Sorry guys I did not know that the error had anything to do with the fuction I am testing with.

Comment: @ereOn to think that the score has "nothing" to do with closing is a little naive: low scores do encourage close votes, and high scores discourage them. Still I agree that that's not what upvotes are for.

Comment: Now that the definition of `fun` has been edited in, this is indeed a real question.

Comment: Not only did some people not give the OP a chance to fix the question but even when he did so in quick time they still closed it. Anyone who downvoted this after the edit really ought to be brave enough to say why.

Comment: @ildjarn: You don't say. Shame you didn't wait for the edit.

Comment: @Troubadour: then vote to reopen, and vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/163211 to address this problem in the future.

Comment: @Troubadour : I said that to encourage reopen votes; how is your comment constructive?

Comment: @all there is no need to reopen I got a pretty good answer. Unless other people find it interesting for other novices.

Comment: @trutheality: Obviously I voted to re-open, why on earth would you think I hadn't? If you think going to meta will help then you really don't understand the problem. It's really very simple. People need to give posters the opportunity to edit their question. No alteration to the UI is required. It's a people thing.

Comment: @ildjarn: My comment points out that if you had given the poster even the tiniest chance to edit his question then we wouldn't need to vote to re-open. There was nothing constructive about voting to close.

Comment: @Troubadour: I know it's a people thing and I think you underestimate the effect that a UI can have on people.

Comment: @Troubadour : I waited five minutes before voting; that qualifies as "the tiniest chance" in any context, but especially when all that had to be done was pasting another handful of lines of already-written code. Get over it.

Comment: @ildjarn: Five minutes is nothing. He might not even check back within five minutes never mind get together the code. Bearing in mind he didn't know where the error was coming from you can't expect him to instantly work out what to post. What exactly is the rush?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to pass a pointer instead of an actual object reference. Simply dereference the pointer like this:

```
void fun( node &node) {

     if (node.link !=NULL) {  
      fun ( *(node.link) );
    }
```

Comment: Why did this work what is going on here?

Comment: @Mark simple: `link` is a pointer (a `node*`). your function takes a reference (a `node`). Calling `*(node.link)` dereferences the pointer (gets you the `node` that the `node*` was pointing to).

Comment: But why is the error complaining about initialization? Also when I dereferenced it does it stay a reference node?

Comment: The way your "fun" function is declared, the expected argument is a reference to a node. You tried to give it a pointer to a node which is not compatible. The "*(node.link)" statement simply tells the compiler to use the object pointed by the pointer "node.link" which is compatible with the required parameter.

Comment: The initialization error is because the compiler tries to create a "node&" from the provided "node*". And it simply can't.

Comment: @Mr_Hic-up so where does node() constructor come into play? Does it initialize automatically the first time I used node?

Comment: @Mark - You need to understand the difference between **pointer to an object(T*) and the object itself(T)**.

Comment: @Mahesh I think Mr_Hic-up has explained that fairly well but I just want to know how node() constructor works. It's not explained well on most website I visited.

Comment: @Mahesh I want to know when it gets called. Cause I thought I needed to manually call it ?

Comment: @Mark - Please pick up http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201700735/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 book and start reading. You can then start working on linked lists, which would be much easier.

Comment: The "node" constructor "node()" will come into play when you actually create a "node" instance.